# PDFTron localstorage

Tags: pdf, local-storage, pdftron

I'm developing a web app. One of the functionality that I'll have to develop is based on save a lot of pdf file inside local storage from client, for read it more fastest. There is in pdftron something that could help me to do it ?

Thanks and have a good day.

Francesco.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Knowing what kind of app are you building and how users are going to use it will help a lot, as there are different ways to go about this.

Comment: A meeting book app, pdf files sharing. I'm using pdftron offline mode ahd it store files inside indexeddb, but I have another problem, I have to store a pdf files zip , after donwload I have to unzip it and store fils inside indexedb(or store zip directly). Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the disableLocalStorage() method
https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/WebViewer.html#disableLocalStorage__anchor